# For loop in C Language

Tags: c

```
int i=0;
int array[1000]={0};
srandom(23523);
a0=random();
a1=random();
a2=random();
....
a999=random();   //a0,a1,...a999 are some random numbers
for(i=0;i<999;i++){
   ....
   //array[0]=a0 array[1]=a1 array[2]=a2....array[999]=a999
}
```

My goal is to change the values in array to a0, a1...a999. 
How to do it by using for loop in C?

Comment: `int array[3]={543};  //int array with 5 element`

Comment: The only smart move is not to do it that way. But then, it's hard to understand the main goal here.

Comment: By having another array containing the values of `a0`, `a1` and `a2` (or pointers to those variables)?

Comment: No, it is impossible in good crossplatform way. You can not get variable by name, there is no reflection or something like that. Though you can get pointer to first element and go down the stack, pray and hope that it would not crash.

Comment: C has lexical scoping. For what you want to do here, you probably need dynamic scoping, which allows you to abstract over 'whatever is in scope'. In short: this is not something that you can (or should want to) do in C.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, by the way? I get the feeling [we should be discussing your actual problem rather than your solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) (because that solution is never going to work in C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you want. Variable names do not exist at runtime. There is no way to have  `aN` where `N` is variable in C. One way or another, you need to explicitly list the variables, and you need to list them in the right order, and you need to know the number of variables when you write them.

```
// copy variables one by one
array[0] = a0;
array[1] = a1;
array[2] = a2;
```

Or with pointers:

```
// list the variables to create a pointer array, ending in NULL pointer
int *ptr_array[] = { &a0, &a1, &a2, NULL };

// optinal: assert that ptr_array is not too big
assert(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) >= sizeof(ptr_array)/sizeof(ptr_array[0])-1);

// copy using loop
for (i = 0 ; ptr_array[i] != NULL ; ++i) {
    array[i] = *(ptr_array[i]);
}
```

---

Depending on what you want, you could write a tool, which would generate code to do one of these, which would scan the code for some special marking (comment or macro), extract the variable names, and generate C source code file which would do one of the above. But this should be last resort, used only when you can't find a way to do what you want otherwise, as it then requires writing the code generator, and integrating it to the build process. Whatever your actual problem is in this case, there's probably a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the values you don't need a loop.

```
int array[3]= { 0, 14, 22 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the 'a' values into an array and then add the values to the array[arrayLength]

```
int main(){
int i=0, arrayLength=3;
int array[arrayLength]={543};  //int array with 5 element
int a0=0;
int a1=14;
int a2=22;
int aValues[3]={a0, a1, a2}
for(i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
array[i]=aValues[i];
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: typo `arrayLength[i]`, also `int array[arrayLength]={543};` VLA cannot have initializer.

Comment: You cannot even compile this code and it's accepted!?!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 3

int main() {

    int count;
    int array1[MAX_SIZE] = {5,4,3};
    int array2[MAX_SIZE] = {0, 14, 22};

    printf("Values before they get changed:\n");

    for(count = 0; count < MAX_SIZE; count++)
            printf("%d \n", array1[count]);

    for(count = 0; count < MAX_SIZE; count++)
        array1[count] = array2[count];

    printf("\nValues after they get changed:\n");

    for(count = 0; count < MAX_SIZE; count++)
        printf("%d \n", array1[count]);

    return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Values before they get changed:
5
4
3

Values after they get changed:
0
14
22
```